# custom Tableview scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview

I need to show three/ four UI buttons and levels, two image views in a custom cell but there is a condition on the basis of that I need to hide an imageView and when it will be hidden, I need to decrease tableview size and buttons which are below of that image view that will move upward.

For that I am giving required conditions in

`heightForRowAtIndexPath:`
and returning cells height accordingly and in tableview

`cellForRowAtIndexPath:`
Method I am hiding imageView and setting buttons positions which are below of that imageView.

The problem is that:

> 1. TableView is not scrolling smoothly
> 2. Initially at the time of scrolling down everything is working but when I move upward then image is resizing and changing its shape. To solve that I have used AutoLayout but still it is not working.

I need your expert advice. Thanks in advance.[image]